# In the case described below, should regression coefficients be reported?

Tags: reporting, interaction, effects

I am conducting a simple moderation analysis with a continuous predictor X, an ordinal moderator M, and a continuous outcome Y variable.  X was found to have a significant effect on Y, but M did not have a significant effect on Y.  The interaction effects of X*M on Y were also non significant.  However, the conditional effects of X on Y at several different levels of M (not at all levels) were significant (p<.001) and confidence intervals did not include "0".  Would it be appropriate to report the conditional effects in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, no. You could examine the interaction term of a linear model as you did first, or you could test the effect of $X$ at different levels of $M$ individually as you did second, but it doesn't make sense to do both; that's double-dipping.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that it is relevant, then yes.

However, it seems like you want to show that conditional on $M$, the impact of $X$ on $Y$ varies. This is tested for nicely using interaction terms. In your interpretation you might not want to draw the conclusion that based on your last finding, difference in $M$ matter. This is a typical fallacy. You would need to check whether the coefficients on $X$ are significantly different. I guess they are not. A very well written reference explaining the procedure is Gelman & Stern (2006): http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf